# Не замыкать фигуры canvas js

Tags: javascript, canvas

Есть программа которая рисует параметрически заданную функцию,но в конце соединяет конечную точку с начальной(закрывает контур).
Как от этого избавиться? График рисуется в функции RenderFunction.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```html
<input type="text" id="a" onkeyup="Draw()"><br>
<canvas id="canvasId" width="800"  height="800" onMouseUp="activate()" onMouseDown="activate()"></canvas>
<script>
 var zoom = 10;
 var w1 = 0, w2 = 0;
 function init() {
  Draw();
 }

 var Canvas = document.getElementById('canvasId');  
 var Ctx = null;

 var Width = Canvas.width;
 var Height = Canvas.height;

 function MaxX() {
  return zoom;
 }

 function MinX() {
  return -zoom;
 }

 function MaxY() {
  return MaxX() * Height / Width;
 }

 function MinY() {
  return MinX() * Height / Width;
 }

 function XC(x) {
  return (x - MinX()) / (MaxX() - MinX()) * Width - w1;
 }

 function YC(y) {
  return Height - (y - MinY()) / (MaxY() - MinY()) * Height - w2;
 }

 var F2 = function(x) {
   return (((document.getElementById("a").value)*2)*(Math.cos(x)/Math.sin(x)));
 };

 var F1 = function(x) {
   return ((document.getElementById("a").value)*(1-Math.cos(2*x)));
 };

 function Draw() {
  if (Canvas.getContext) {
   Ctx = Canvas.getContext('2d');
   Ctx.clearRect(0,0,Width,Height);
   DrawAxes();
   RenderFunction(F1, F2);
  }
 }


 function XTickDelta() {
  return 1;
 }

 function YTickDelta() {
  return 1;
 }

 function DrawAxes() {
  Ctx.strokeStyle="#000";
  Ctx.save();
  Ctx.lineWidth = 1;
  Ctx.beginPath();
  Ctx.moveTo(XC(0),YC(0));
  Ctx.lineTo(XC(0),YC(MaxY())+w2);
  Ctx.stroke();
  
  var del = Math.floor(zoom / 10);

  Ctx.beginPath();
  Ctx.moveTo(XC(0),YC(0));
  Ctx.lineTo(XC(0),YC(MinY())+w2);
  Ctx.stroke();
  var delta = YTickDelta();
  var tt3 = Math.floor(-w2 / 10);
  tt3 = (tt3 > 0) ? tt3 : 1;
  for (var i = 1; (i * delta) < MaxY()+ tt3; ++i) {   //сетка
   Ctx.beginPath();
   if(del < 2){
    Ctx.moveTo(XC(0) - Width/2 + w1,YC(i * delta));
    Ctx.lineTo(XC(0) + Width/2 + w1,YC(i * delta));
    //Ctx.fillText(i, XC(0)+2,YC(i * delta)-3);
   }else if(del > 1 && i % del == 0){
    Ctx.moveTo(XC(0) - Width/2 + w1,YC(i * delta));
    Ctx.lineTo(XC(0) + Width/2 + w1,YC(i * delta));
    //Ctx.fillText(i, XC(0)+2,YC(i * delta)-3);
   }
   Ctx.stroke();  
  }

  var delta = YTickDelta();
  var tt4 = Math.floor(-w2 / 10);
  tt4 = (tt4 < 0) ? tt4 : -1;
  for (var i = 1; (i * delta) > MinY()+ tt4; --i) {     //сетка
   Ctx.beginPath();
   if(i == 0) Ctx.lineWidth = 3; else Ctx.lineWidth = 1;
   if(del < 2){
    Ctx.moveTo(XC(0) - Width/2 + w1,YC(i * delta));
    Ctx.lineTo(XC(0) + Width/2 + w1,YC(i * delta));
    //Ctx.fillText(i, XC(0)+2,YC(i * delta)-3);
   }else if(del > 1 && i % del == 0){
    Ctx.moveTo(XC(0) - Width/2 + w1,YC(i * delta));
    Ctx.lineTo(XC(0) + Width/2 + w1,YC(i * delta));
    //Ctx.fillText(i, XC(0)+2,YC(i * delta)-3);
   }
   Ctx.stroke();  
  }  
  
  Ctx.beginPath();
  Ctx.moveTo(XC(0),YC(0));
  Ctx.lineTo(XC(MaxX())+w1,YC(0));
  Ctx.stroke();
  
  Ctx.beginPath();
  Ctx.moveTo(XC(0),YC(0));
  Ctx.lineTo(XC(MinX())+w1,YC(0));
  Ctx.stroke();
  
  var delta = XTickDelta();
  var tt1 = Math.floor(w1 / 10);
  tt1 = (tt1 > 0) ? tt1 : 1;
  for (var i = 1; (i * delta) < MaxX() + tt1; ++i) {     //сетка
   Ctx.beginPath();
   if(del < 2){
    Ctx.moveTo(XC(i * delta),YC(0)-Height/2 + w2);
    Ctx.lineTo(XC(i * delta),YC(0)+Height/2 + w2);
    //Ctx.fillText(i, XC(i * delta)+2,YC(0)-3);
   }else if(del > 1 && i % del == 0){
    Ctx.moveTo(XC(i * delta),YC(0)-Height/2 + w2);
    Ctx.lineTo(XC(i * delta),YC(0)+Height/2 + w2);
    //Ctx.fillText(i, XC(i * delta)+2,YC(0)-3);
   }
   Ctx.stroke();  
  }

  var delta = XTickDelta();
  var tt2 = Math.floor(w1 / 10);
  tt2 = (tt2 < 0) ? tt2 : -1;
  for (var i = 1; (i * delta) > MinX()+ tt2; --i) {      //сетка
   Ctx.beginPath();
   if(i == 0) Ctx.lineWidth = 3; else Ctx.lineWidth = 1;
   if(del < 2){
    Ctx.moveTo(XC(i * delta),YC(0)-Height/2 + w2);
    Ctx.lineTo(XC(i * delta),YC(0)+Height/2 + w2);
    //Ctx.fillText(i, XC(i * delta)+2,YC(0)-3);
   }else if(del > 1 && i % del == 0){
    Ctx.moveTo(XC(i * delta),YC(0)-Height/2 + w2);
    Ctx.lineTo(XC(i * delta),YC(0)+Height/2 + w2);
    //Ctx.fillText(i, XC(i * delta)+2,YC(0)-3);
   }
   Ctx.stroke();  
  }
  Ctx.restore();
 }


 var XSTEP = (MaxX()-MinX())/Width;

 function RenderFunction(f1, f2){
  var first = true;
  Ctx.beginPath();
  Ctx.strokeStyle="#FF0000";
  for (var z = MinX(); z <= MaxX(); z += XSTEP){
   var y = f1(Math.abs(z));
   var x = f2(Math.abs(z));

   if (first){
    Ctx.moveTo(XC(x),YC(y));
    first = false;
   }else{
    Ctx.lineTo(XC(x),YC(y));
   }
  }
  Ctx.stroke();
 }

 Canvas.addEventListener("wheel", onWheel);
 function onWheel(e) {
  e = e || window.event;
  var delta = e.deltaY || e.detail || e.wheelDelta;
  zoom += (-delta > 0 && zoom > 1) ? -1 : 1;
  Draw();
 }
 
 var activ=false;
 function activate() {
  activ=!activ;
 }
 Canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", function(e){
  if(activ) {
   w1 -= e.movementX;
   w2 -= e.movementY;
   Draw();
  }
 });
 
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Потому что вы не функцию рисуете, посмотрите на массив точек, который рисуется в вашем примере выведя его лог.

Вот что получается если точки отсортировать:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```js
init()
```

```html
<input id="a" value="2"/><br>
<canvas id="canvasId"></canvas>

<script>
var zoom = 10;
var w1 = 0, w2 = 0;
function init() {
    Draw();
}

var Canvas = document.getElementById('canvasId');  
var Ctx = null;

var Width = Canvas.width;
var Height = Canvas.height;

function MaxX() {
    return zoom;
}

function MinX() {
    return -zoom;
}

function MaxY() {
    return MaxX() * Height / Width;
}

function MinY() {
    return MinX() * Height / Width;
}

function XC(x) {
    return (x - MinX()) / (MaxX() - MinX()) * Width - w1;
}

function YC(y) {
    return Height - (y - MinY()) / (MaxY() - MinY()) * Height - w2;
}

var F2 = function(x) {
  return (((document.getElementById("a").value)*2)*(Math.cos(x)/Math.sin(x)));
};

var F1 = function(x) {
  return ((document.getElementById("a").value)*(1-Math.cos(2*x)));
};

function Draw() {
    if (Canvas.getContext) {
        Ctx = Canvas.getContext('2d');
        Ctx.clearRect(0,0,Width,Height);
        DrawAxes();
        RenderFunction(F1, F2);
    }
}


function XTickDelta() {
    return 1;
}

function YTickDelta() {
    return 1;
}

function DrawAxes() {
    Ctx.strokeStyle="#000";
    Ctx.save();
    Ctx.lineWidth = 1;
    Ctx.beginPath();
    Ctx.moveTo(XC(0),YC(0));
    Ctx.lineTo(XC(0),YC(MaxY())+w2);
    Ctx.stroke();

    var del = Math.floor(zoom / 10);

    Ctx.beginPath();
    Ctx.moveTo(XC(0),YC(0));
    Ctx.lineTo(XC(0),YC(MinY())+w2);
    Ctx.stroke();
    var delta = YTickDelta();
    var tt3 = Math.floor(-w2 / 10);
    tt3 = (tt3 > 0) ? tt3 : 1;
    for (var i = 1; (i * delta) < MaxY()+ tt3; ++i) {           //сетка
        Ctx.beginPath();
        if(del < 2){
            Ctx.moveTo(XC(0) - Width/2 + w1,YC(i * delta));
            Ctx.lineTo(XC(0) + Width/2 + w1,YC(i * delta));
            //Ctx.fillText(i, XC(0)+2,YC(i * delta)-3);
        }else if(del > 1 && i % del == 0){
            Ctx.moveTo(XC(0) - Width/2 + w1,YC(i * delta));
            Ctx.lineTo(XC(0) + Width/2 + w1,YC(i * delta));
            //Ctx.fillText(i, XC(0)+2,YC(i * delta)-3);
        }
        Ctx.stroke();  
    }

    var delta = YTickDelta();
    var tt4 = Math.floor(-w2 / 10);
    tt4 = (tt4 < 0) ? tt4 : -1;
    for (var i = 1; (i * delta) > MinY()+ tt4; --i) {                   //сетка
        Ctx.beginPath();
        if(i == 0) Ctx.lineWidth = 3; else Ctx.lineWidth = 1;
        if(del < 2){
            Ctx.moveTo(XC(0) - Width/2 + w1,YC(i * delta));
            Ctx.lineTo(XC(0) + Width/2 + w1,YC(i * delta));
            //Ctx.fillText(i, XC(0)+2,YC(i * delta)-3);
        }else if(del > 1 && i % del == 0){
            Ctx.moveTo(XC(0) - Width/2 + w1,YC(i * delta));
            Ctx.lineTo(XC(0) + Width/2 + w1,YC(i * delta));
            //Ctx.fillText(i, XC(0)+2,YC(i * delta)-3);
        }
        Ctx.stroke();  
    }  

    Ctx.beginPath();
    Ctx.moveTo(XC(0),YC(0));
    Ctx.lineTo(XC(MaxX())+w1,YC(0));
    Ctx.stroke();

    Ctx.beginPath();
    Ctx.moveTo(XC(0),YC(0));
    Ctx.lineTo(XC(MinX())+w1,YC(0));
    Ctx.stroke();

    var delta = XTickDelta();
    var tt1 = Math.floor(w1 / 10);
    tt1 = (tt1 > 0) ? tt1 : 1;
    for (var i = 1; (i * delta) < MaxX() + tt1; ++i) {                  //сетка
        Ctx.beginPath();
        if(del < 2){
            Ctx.moveTo(XC(i * delta),YC(0)-Height/2 + w2);
            Ctx.lineTo(XC(i * delta),YC(0)+Height/2 + w2);
            //Ctx.fillText(i, XC(i * delta)+2,YC(0)-3);
        }else if(del > 1 && i % del == 0){
            Ctx.moveTo(XC(i * delta),YC(0)-Height/2 + w2);
            Ctx.lineTo(XC(i * delta),YC(0)+Height/2 + w2);
            //Ctx.fillText(i, XC(i * delta)+2,YC(0)-3);
        }
        Ctx.stroke(); 
 
    }

    var delta = XTickDelta();
    var tt2 = Math.floor(w1 / 10);
    tt2 = (tt2 < 0) ? tt2 : -1;
    for (var i = 1; (i * delta) > MinX()+ tt2; --i) {                       //сетка
        Ctx.beginPath();
        if(i == 0) Ctx.lineWidth = 3; else Ctx.lineWidth = 1;
        if(del < 2){
            Ctx.moveTo(XC(i * delta),YC(0)-Height/2 + w2);
            Ctx.lineTo(XC(i * delta),YC(0)+Height/2 + w2);
            //Ctx.fillText(i, XC(i * delta)+2,YC(0)-3);
        }else if(del > 1 && i % del == 0){
            Ctx.moveTo(XC(i * delta),YC(0)-Height/2 + w2);
            Ctx.lineTo(XC(i * delta),YC(0)+Height/2 + w2);
            //Ctx.fillText(i, XC(i * delta)+2,YC(0)-3);
        }
        Ctx.stroke();  
    }
    Ctx.restore();
}


var XSTEP = (MaxX()-MinX())/Width;

function RenderFunction(f1, f2){
    let pts = [];
    for (var z = MinX(); z <= MaxX(); z += XSTEP)
        pts.push([XC( f2(Math.abs(z))),YC(f1(Math.abs(z)))])
    Ctx.beginPath();
    Ctx.strokeStyle="#FF0000";
    pts = pts.sort((a,b) => a[0]-b[0]).forEach((e,i) => {
      Ctx[i?'lineTo':'moveTo'](e[0], e[1]);
    });
    Ctx.stroke();
}

Canvas.addEventListener("wheel", onWheel);
function onWheel(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    var delta = e.deltaY || e.detail || e.wheelDelta;
    zoom += (-delta > 0 && zoom > 1) ? -1 : 1;
    Draw();
}

var activ=false;
function activate() {
    activ=!activ;
}
Canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", function(e){
    if(activ) {
        w1 -= e.movementX;
        w2 -= e.movementY;
        Draw();
    }
});

</script>
```